# is a positive ray is a convex cone?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

A definition of a convex cone is given [here](https://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/convex-cones-and-the-hilbert-metric/), could anyone tell me whether a ray $C=\{(x,y): y=mx, x\ge 0,y \ge 0, m=\tan \theta, 0< \theta< 90\}$ on the positive quadrant satisfies the condition $4$? I can see 1,2,3, are satisfied. Thanks!

Comment: That definition is not the standard one (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone). Both the standard definition and the one your are looking at hold for any ray.

Comment: This is an unusual definition for a cone. There are not many options for $f,g$ so Property 4 is straightforward to establish.